# Writing user defined function to evaluate the Saha equation with for-loops for an expected output

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, user-defined-functions, physics, astronomy

I am trying to create a function that evaluates the Saha function for certain values of temperature and electron pressure. The question is a little in depth so I will provide as much detail as possible about past code used before this section.

**Previous sections code**

*Evaluating the partition function (part 1):*

```
k= 8.617333262145179e-05  
T=10000. 
g=1.0
Ca_ion_energies = np.array([6.1131554, 11.871719, 50.91316, 67.2732, 84.34])  #in eV
Ca_partition_values= []

def partfunc_E(chiI,T):
    for chiI in Ca_ion_energies:
        elem = 0
        for i in np.arange(chiI):
            elem = elem + (g*np.exp(-(i/(k*T))))
        Ca_partition_values.append(elem)
    return Ca_partition_values

print(partfunc_E(Ca_ion_energies,T))
```

Output:

```
[1.455902590894594, 1.45633321917395, 1.4563345239240013, 1.4563345239240013, 1.4563345239240013]
```

*Evaluating the Boltzmann equation (part 2):*

```
chiI = np.array([6.1131554, 11.871719, 50.91316, 67.2732, 84.34])  #in eV
k= 8.617333262145179e-05
T=10000.

def boltz_E(chiI,T,I,i):
    Z_1 = partfunc_E(chiI,T)
    ratio = np.exp(-i/(k*T)) / Z_1
    return ratio [I-1] 

print(Ca_ion_energies)
print("i Fraction in level i for I=1 (neutral)")
print("- -------------------------------------")
for n in range(0,10):
    print(n,boltz_E(chiI,10000,1,n))
```

Output:

```
[ 6.1131554 11.871719  50.91316   67.2732    84.34     ]
i Fraction in level i for I=1 (neutral)
- -------------------------------------
0 0.6868591389658425
1 0.21522358567610525
2 0.06743914320048579
3 0.021131689732463026
4 0.006621500359539954
5 0.002074811222693332
6 0.0006501308428703751
7 0.0002037149733085943
8 6.383298193775377e-05
9 2.0001718660577703e-05
```

**Question I need help with (and my code so far):**

*Evaluating the Saha equation (part 3):*

The instructions for this section are as follows:

The simplest way to get this ratio is to set  _=1  (i.e. the neutral atom) to some value (e.g. unity), evaluate the next ionisation-stage populations successively from the Saha equation in a for loop, and at the end divide them by the sum of all the    on the same scale. You will find the numpy np.sum function useful to get the total over all stages. We want temperature T to be 5000K and electron pressure Pe to be 100.0 N/m^2.

FYI: I is the ionisation stage, Z_1 is the partition function from part 1, Z_I is the partition function for stage I+1, Pe is the electron pressure, chiI are the ionisation energies (for Calcium in my code), T is temperature and the function that "fraction" is set equal to is the Saha equation.

It should start something like:

def saha_E(chiI,T,Pe,I):

compute Saha population fraction N_I/N

input: ionisation energies, temperature, electron pressure, ion stage

1. Compute the partition functions
2. Loop over each ionisation stage that you have an energy for, computing the fraction via the saha equation. Note that the first stage should be set to 1.
3. Divide each stage by the total
4. Return the fraction of the requested stage

*My code attempt:*

```
k= 8.617333262145179e-05  
T=10000.  
g=1.0
Ca_ion_energies = np.array([6.1131554, 11.871719, 50.91316, 67.2732, 84.34])  
N_I = 1
h = 6.626e-34
m = 9.11e-31
fractions = []
fraction_sum = []

def saha_E(chiI,T,Pe,I):
    Z_1 = partfunc_E(chiI,T)
    Z_I = partfunc_E(chiI+1,T)
    for I in Ca_ion_energies:
        fraction = (N_I*(Z_I/Z_1)*((2*k*T)/((h**3)*Pe))*((2*np.pi*m*k*T)**(3/2))*np.exp(-I/(k*T)))
        fractions.append(fraction)
        fraction_sum.append(np.sum(fractions))
        for i in fractions:
            i/fraction_sum
            return fraction

print("For ionisation energies (in eV) of:",chiI)
print()
print("I Fraction in stage I")
print("- -------------------")
for I in range(0,6):
    print(I,saha_E(chiI,5000,100.0,I))
```

I am instructed also that the output should be something similar to:

```
For ionisation energies (in eV) of: [  6.11  11.87  50.91  67.27  84.34]

I  Fraction in stage I
-  -------------------
1 0.999998720736
2 1.27926351211e-06
3 7.29993420039e-52
4 1.3474665329e-113
5 1.54848994685e-192
```

Firstly, I don't think my code is correct but it is the best I can do which is why I need some help, but also, this code is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'
```

If my code is totally wrong please tell me as I have spent so much time trying to figure this out already.

**Edit**

This question is still not completely answered, please keep commenting!

Comment: Several problems in your code. 1- `i/fraction_sum` only work if both terms are numpy arrays, not lists. 2- Why is the result of `i/fraction_sum` not assigned to anything? 3- Your nested loop runs only once and returns. Are you sure the `return` is at the right place?

Comment: I have now moved the ```return``` inline with the first for-loop, thanks for that, I totally overlooked it. 

I assigned now ```ratio = i/fraction_sum``` and appended the results to another array. I tried making terms in ```i/fraction_sum``` arrays using ```np.array``` but I am still getting the same error, so then I used ```np.divide``` but returned the error again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem well, my approach is to calculate the "fractions" and "fractions sums" in a single loop on the various energies, and normalize only once we are outside the loop.

Also, careful with the scope of your code. I pushed some variables you declared outside of the function inside of it because there is no reason to keep them alive outside of the function's scope.

Careful also not to use the same variable twice. Your function takes a `I` argument but then has a `I` variable in a for loop.

As said in the chat, you want to write dosctrings and comments so that you know where you are going even before touching any code. Here is a base to complete:

```
import numpy as np 

# Constants.
k = 8.617333262145179e-05  
g = 1.0
h = 6.626e-34
m = 9.11e-31
Ca_ion_energies = np.array([6.1131554, 11.871719, 50.91316, 67.2732, 84.34]) # in eV.


# Partition function.
def partfunc_E(chiI, T):
    """This function returns the partition of blablabla.

       args:
       ------
       :chiI: (array or list) the energy levels of a chosen ion.
       :T: (float) the temperature at which kT will be calculated."""

    Ca_partition_values = []
    for energy_level in chiI: # For each energy level.
        elem = 0
        for i in np.arange(energy_level): # From 0 to current energy level.
            elem += g*np.exp(-(i/(k*T)))
        Ca_partition_values.append(elem)
    return np.array(Ca_partition_values) # Conversion to numpy array to support operations later.

print(partfunc_E(Ca_ion_energies, T=10000))


# Boltzmann equation.
def boltz_E(chiI, T, I, i):
    Z_1 = partfunc_E(chiI, T)
    ratio = np.exp(-i/(k*T)) / Z_1
    return ratio[I-1] 

print(Ca_ion_energies)
print("i Fraction in level i for I=1 (neutral)")
print("- -------------------------------------")
for n in range(0,10):
    print(n, boltz_E(Ca_ion_energies, T=10000, I=1, i=n))


# Saha equation.
def saha_E(chiI, T, Pe, i):
    p = partfunc_E(chiI, T)
    Z_ratios = np.array([p[n]/p[0] for n in range(len(chiI))])
    fractions = []
    fractions_sum = []
    for n, I in enumerate(chiI):
        fraction = Z_ratios[n]*((2*k*T)/((h**3)*Pe))*((2*np.pi*m*k*T)**(3/2))*np.exp(-I/(k*T))
        fractions.append(fraction)
        fractions_sum.append(np.sum(fractions))

    # Let's normalize the array before returning it.
    fractions = np.divide(fractions, fractions_sum)
    return fractions[i]


print("For ionisation energies (in eV) of:", Ca_ion_energies)
print()
print("I Fraction in stage n")
print("- -------------------")
for n in range(0, 4):
    print(n, saha_E(Ca_ion_energies, T=5000, Pe=100.0, i=n))
```

Comment: When I run this I am still getting the error : ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: Ah, that would be because `Z_1` and `Z_I` are list. I'll edit.

Comment: May I just ask first, the line of code I wrote ```Z_I = partfunc_E(chiI+1, T)```. That is meant to calculate the partition function from part 1 for the I+1 term, is that the correct way (just adding +1 as I have in the functions variable ```chiI```) to do so? @Guimoute

Comment: I have to admit I only looked at part 3, but `partfunc_E` has an issue too actually. You take `chiI` as an argument and proceed to immediately overwrite it by using it in `for chiI in ...`.

Comment: After running your edit, I have received the error: ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,225) (5,) ```
And oh okay, well it gives me the correct values for partfunc_E (we were given the values to expect as an output). What should I change that to and will that make a difference in part 3's calculation? @Guimoute

Comment: After which line? I can only fix one part if I can assume the previous works as intended :\ Can you please confirm whether `partfunc_E` yields the expected output before we go further? Edit: ok I saw your edit. No it won't make a difference then, that function will return a list with the same size as `Ca_ion_energies` so that's all I need to know from part 1. :)

Comment: The code for partfunc_E in part a gives the correct output (which I provided underneath it in the op). Part 2's code also gives the correct output. 
Just to be clear also:
The error I just commented back with ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,65) (5,) ``` is for running the code you provided for part 3.
Edit: Just saw your comment. Any thoughts on the error in part 3 now then? @Guimoute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211371/discussion-between-guimoute-and-user1997).